# Specify Chef provider for windows_feature

Tags: ruby, windows-server-2008, chef-infra

I'm trying to use Chef (chef-solo) to manage my Windows Server 2008 R2 installation. Chef provides `windows_feature` to add roles/features to a Windows server. By default, `windows_feature` uses DISM to install roles. However, to my knowledge, not all roles (e.g., RDS-RD-Server) are able to be added via DISM.

I could presumably use `Chef::Provider::WindowsFeature::ServerManagerCmd` (identified in the Windows cookbook readme: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows), but it doesn't look like that is a real class (browsing the source code there). Also, servermanagercmd is deprecated (though it would work).

I wouldn't mind even using a powershell block to add the role, but I'm having a hard time ensuring idempotence. It seems like the `not_if` command shell is some weird mingwin shell rather than CMD.

Here's a sample of what I've tried using powershell (doesn't work):

```
powershell "install_rds_server" do
  code %Q{
    Import-Module Servermanager
    Add-WindowsFeature RDS-RD-Server
  }.strip
  not_if %Q{
    powershell "Import-Module Servermanager; $check = get-windowsfeature -name RDS-RD-Server; if ($check.Installed -ne \"True\") { exit 1 }"
  }.strip
end
```

What would be the recommended Chef way of adding this role?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
windows_feature 'RDS-RD-Server' do
  provider Chef::Provider::WindowsFeature::ServerManagerCmd
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get the following error when I try that: `FATAL: NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Provider::WindowsFeature::ServerManagerCmd`.

Comment: You'll need to have the Windows cookbook in your run_list for that provider to exist.

Comment: No, he needs to add `depends "windows"` into his cookbook's metadata.rb